# How to test android based mobile pages on web browsers with the help of plugins?

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, android-browser

I want to test android mobile based pages on browsers like chrome or mozilla. Is there any plugins available so I can directly test them on these browsers without running them on device or emulator?

Answer (score 3):

I created this chrome extension to help test. It's not a perfect replacement for actual device testing, but it's a start.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobile-tester/elmekokodcohlommfikpmojheggnbelo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: it ads only a resize functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This site shows you one possible way to do it.

http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/emulate-mobile-browser-in-firefox.html

Once you have your user agent set you can just resize the window to be phone screen sized.

Answer (score 0):

On Mozilla Firefox, you can use Selenium IDE to emulate clicks, typing and other actions. Personally, I have never tested it for mobile web applications.

http://seleniumhq.org/